# jQuery event load at onFinish execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

On my project I have implemented a code that works on jQuery.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
            $("#startProgressTimer").click(function() {
                $("#progressTimer").progressTimer({
                    timeLimit: $("#restTime").val(),
                    onFinish: function(){
                    $('#startProgressTimer').fadeOut(2000);
                    $('#progressTimer').fadeOut(2000);

                    $('#testId').show();// NOT WORKING

                   }
                });
            });
</script>
```

I have a captcha that should be loaded when the onFinish event is executed. `$('#startProgressTimer').fadeOut(2000);` and `$('#progressTimer').fadeOut(2000);` is working properly. But `$('#testId').show();` is not working. Here is the "testId" div element. `<div id="testId" style="visibility:hidden"><?php include'cap_index.php'; ?></div>`. This element should work when the onFinish event is executed IMMEDIATELY AFTER the first two elements fades out properly but its not working. The captcha does not appears. Please help.

Comment: can you go deeper in what "doesn't work" means? Does the div appear? Has the page a php extention? Does the php include get executed even if the div is hidden?

Comment: 1st - Doesn't work means that the DIV element is not appearing when the onFinish event is executed (however the 1st two elements are being well executed.. they fade out properly in time)

2nd - DIV appears when the visibility is NOT hidden (currently hidden).

3rd - Yes the page has a PHP extension as you can see I have included a PHP page cap_index.php there.

4th - When the DIV is hidden the element is not shown only. It is executed only when the captcha is filled and submit button is clicked. (Its a CAPTCHA i m mentioning )

Comment: Try: `$("#testId").css('visibility', 'visible');`

Answer (score 3):

Jquery `show` won't work with elements hidden by `visibility: hidden;`, you could show it as follows:

```
$("#testId").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Now, if you wan't `#testId` to show after the other two elements are hidden, use a callback function for the `fadeOut` call:

```
$('#startProgressTimer, #progressTimer').fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $("#testId").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: works but partially... it now shows up as I exactly wanted... BUT now after I verify the captcha and click on submit button the captcha hides off and #startProgressTimer appears again instead of showing the success or error message. But if my visibility is not hidden then the captcha works perfectly and the success message shows up.